# Linode Docker Marketplace App: Where is the config stored?

Tags: linode

Using the Docker App from the Marketplace, I can set a command to run on the Linode creation. What if I need to change the command like changing the image tag?  Where can I find the info in Debian so I can edit it after creation?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests, I figured out that the command is not stored in the Linode and not run at reboot. Restarting a container at reboot is done by adding a restart policy in the Docker Run command.

In case I need to update the image with a newer version, I need to stop the current one and do a Docker Run with the new image.